# Applet not loading

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, liveconnect

I have a Java web application. It was running fine until last week. We released a new version of our code and one of our applets is not getting launched anymore from our main java application. We did not change anything in the called applet, nor on the surrounding code.

The strange thing is, it looks like it's working on 64-bit pcs but not on 32-bit versions.

Used java version: 1.8.0_65.
Used web browser: Internet Explorer 11

Java console log of pc where it is not working (32-bit):

```
cache: Reading Signers from xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar | C:\Temp\java_cache\6.0\39\123b7967-55895556-3.4.0.2-.idx
cache: Done readSigners(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar)
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx .jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 402489 us, pluginInit dt 2037296772 us, TotalTime: 2037699261 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
preloader: Stop progressCheck thread queue.size()=0
```

Java console log of pc where it is working fine (64-bit):

```
cache: Reading Signers from 3871 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar | C:\Temp\java_cache\6.0\52\13969c74-2c189342-3.4.0.2-.idx
cache: Done readSigners(xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar)
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
network: Created version ID: 3.4.0.2
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 546952 us, pluginInit dt 55559621 us, TotalTime: 56106573 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
security: Grant liveconnect connect perm for xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: java.security.Permissions@2e9808 (
 ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.audio")
 ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "stopThread")
 ("com.sun.deploy.security.SecureCookiePermission" "origin.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
 ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:0" "listen,resolve")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "path.separator" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.vendor" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "browser.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor.url" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "browser" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "browser.vendor" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.name" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.name" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javaws.*" "read,write")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javaplugin.vm.options" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "mrj.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "jnlp.*" "read,write")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javaplugin.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.vendor" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.name" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "file.separator" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "line.separator" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vendor" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.specification.name" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.specification.vendor" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.vm.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javapi.*" "read,write")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.class.version" "read")
 ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "http.agent" "read")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/-" "*:*")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "*:*")
)

security: Javascript from a non secure page is accessing privileged code. Consider using HTTPS protocol when using Javascript -> Java liveconnect calls.
Starting processing threads
```

The manifest file of the applet also seems ok:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Trusted-Only: true
Application-Name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Built-By: xxxxx
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_34
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: Eclipse
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (long list, including the ip of the applet)
Archiver-Version: Subversion
Codebase: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (long list, including the ip of the applet)
```

Can anyone help me with solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused the problem: the surrounding code was hanging in one of the javascript functions on the 32-bit PCs (due to a wrong file path).
This caused the screen to freeze and the applet not to be executed.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, could you please explain a bit more on this "surrounding code was hanging in one of the javascript functions on the 32-bit PCs" ? I'm facing a similar issue.